# Android: Webview embeded YouTube Video Works on Nexus 7 (4.2.2), not Samsung Intercept (2.2)

Tags: android, webview, youtube

OK so I've been working at this a bit and got a YouTube video to work while embedded in an iframe with my Nexus 7, but then I tested it with an old Samsung Intercept running 2.2 and I'm getting the video thumbnail, but when I hit play it just goes to a black frame and stops. Here's the code that I'm currently using:

```
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    Point size = new Point();
    WindowManager w = getWindowManager();

      if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
      {
            w.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
            width = size.x;
            height = size.y; 
      }
      else
      {
            Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay(); 
            width = d.getWidth(); 
            height = d.getHeight(); 
      }

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.welcomeVideo);
    String play= "<html><body><div align=\"center\"> <iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"" + width/2 + "\" height=\"" + height/4 + "\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/9DNAyD4ll6E?html5=1\" frameborder=\"0\"></div></body></html>";
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    });
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8)
    {
        webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    }
    else
    {
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    }
    webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.loadData(play, "text/html", "utf-8");
    webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
```

As you can see, I've tried a couple things, such as enabling plugins, making the browser appear as Chrome, and appending HTML5=1 to the end of the YouTube video link. I'm not sure if it's just because of the version of the phone or what, but my client also tested it out and said that it's not working (though hasn't responded to me yet on *how* it's not working, so that may be an entirely different issue). Is there a better way to go about this for the most compatibility? If not I may just use an intent to launch the YouTube app, but my client is pretty specific about wanting it to be embedded on the page while having a broad range of supported devices.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe the reason for this mismatch is the HTML5 support in the browser at the time of Android 2.2 vs Android 4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android 2.1 & 2.2 had partial Video Element support.

Please refer : http://caniuse.com/#feat=video.